# "Is my email read?" tracking not requiring permission "app wants to Read, send, delete, and manage your email" in Gmail

Tags: gmail, tracking

Many Chrome extensions offer the tracking feature *"Has my email been read?"* in Gmail. But those I've tested require this, which I don't want:

[image]

**Question: are there solutions that allow Gmail email tracking without requiring such permissions?**

Comment: Send an HTML mail that includes an image loaded from a webserver. Pass a unique identifier for the image or similar so you know which mail you sent was opened.

Comment: +1, BUT, that requires some programming knowledge & the OP may be asking for an off the shelf solution

Comment: @ivanivan: I already did that, but then it adds a bunch of new questions: whenever I re-open a past mail I sent, I'm displaying the tracking pixel myself, and then this sends me an unwanted notification :) There's practically no way to distinguish the mail open actions from myself or from the recipient. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486513/do-not-log-my-own-visits-with-a-tracking-pixel-web-beacon

Comment: @Mawg No i'm ok about programming it myself.